# Absorbing markov chain and step probability

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have been using an absorbing markov chain to calculate the expected number of steps to transition to my absorbing state. I have calculated this correctly by following the wiki guide https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain

Now I have my P transition matrix as well as my fundamental matrix is it possible for me to calculate the probability of transitioning from my start state to my absorbing state in n steps?

Thanks

Comment: The absorbing time follows a discrete phase-type distribution (which you can find the link in that page too) so you can calculate the probability, moment, etc similarly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Reading up on the discrete phase type distribution I can't see how it can be used to answer my question. I'm sure it can as you suggested but I seem to be at a loss with it. Can you please shed some light on this please? Thanks

Comment: When you want to calculate the $n$ step transition probabilities, you raise the transition matrix $P$ to the power $n$ and look at the relevant entries. And when you express $P$ in canonical form, you will see when you raise to the power $n$, there is a geometric series of matrix in the top right hand block, and that is why when you sum to infinity it will related to the fundamental matrix. If you look at the probability of absorption on or before step $n$, just look at $P^n$ is sufficient.

Comment: If you want the absorption exactly happens at step $n$, then you require the chain to stay at the transient states before step $n$, which you can refer to the matrix $P^{n-1}$, and absorb at state $n$. The discrete phase type distribution is just like a geometric distribution, when there is only 1 absorption state. You can follow the above argument to derive the pmf and CDF listed on that page.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for your explanation